# I am curious about the Cobalt Youtube certification test process

Tags: youtube, cobalt

During the YouTube certification 2017 testing process

It says "WARNING: The current user agent is not in the 2016 YouTube-required fomat" on a red line
Why is it floating like that?

(cobalt version : 10.52708)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLjA3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

let me clarify your question.
1. Are you asking why the warning message is displayed although your UA string meets our requirement? In this case, please share your UA string.
2. Are you asking why the warning message says "2016" not "2017"? In this case, I will fix it to say "2017".

I fixed #2.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I have confirmed that the warning message has been changed to 2017. Thank you.
Is the reason that WARNING MESSAGE is displayed because of UA string?

Comment: Yes the warning message itself is because your UA string does not follow YouTube's requirement. What is your UA string?